# R - apply function across every row

Tags: r, vectorization, apply

I have the following function to get the week from a given date

```
getWeek <- function (year, month, day) {
  date <- as.Date(paste(year, month, day, sep = "-"), "%Y-%b-%d")
  week <- format(date, "%W")
  return(week)
}
```

I want to apply the above function to following data.frame `x` and create a new column in `x`. I tried using `mapply` but it gives me `NA`.

```
> dput(x)
structure(list(year = c(2003L, 2010L, 2012L, 2012L, 2007L), month = structure(c(3L, 
10L, 9L, 8L, 6L), .Label = c(" Apr", " Aug", " Dec", " Feb", 
" Jan", " Jul", " Jun", " Mar", " May", " Nov", " Oct", " Sep"
), class = "factor"), day = c(4L, 3L, 25L, 26L, 18L), Humidity = structure(c(38L, 
71L, 73L, 49L, 87L), .Label = c("10", "100", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
"58", "59", "6", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", 
"68", "69", "7", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", 
"78", "79", "8", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", 
"88", "89", "9", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "96", "97", "N/A"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("year", "month", "day", "Humidity"
), row.names = c(2605L, 80763L, 108420L, 106512L, 54342L), class = "data.frame")


>  mapply(getWeek, x$year, x$month, x$day)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA
```

I need `getWeek` to be applied to each row in `x`? Is `mapply` the right one to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your function is already vectorized, you don't need to use apply at all.  Instead just call it with the correct variables (once you fix the error below, your `mapply` solution will work as well):

```
with(x, getWeek(year, month, day))
```

However, you have a leading space before each month.  So either you need to use the format string `%Y- %b-%d' or remove it:`x$month <- gsub('^ ', '', x$month)`

Answer (score 1):

Your `getWeek` function is broken.

It should look something like this:

```
getWeek <- function (year, month, day) {
  date <- as.Date(paste(year, month, day, sep = "-"), "%Y- %b-%d")
  week <- format(date, "%W")
  return(week)
}
```

You need to account for the leading space in your months.

Of course,

```
x$month <- substring(x$month,2)
```

would fix your issue as well.

Comment: Had to pick one answer and I picked the earliest one.